# KDB - Is there a limit to the number of functions called at one time when updating tables?

Tags: kdb

I’ve been running a number of functions to update a table and I keep adding more functions as I wish to update and call other various items. I have not run into any issues yet (currently at 7 functions) but I’m mindful that there may be a limit. I did find that there is a limit of 8 parameters for a single function but nothing noting a limit on the below. If not, great. I wanted to be mindful as I scale up.

```
updateTable: FuncG FuncF FunE FuncD FuncC FuncB FuncA ::;  // max number of functions?
t: updateTable t;
```

Comment: There is no limit on how many functions you can call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a fake update statement with loads of function calls, and it seems like you're fine:

```
q)t:([]a:1 2 3)
q)f:{x+1}
q)value "update ",(raze 1000#enlist"f "),"a from t"
a   
----
1001
1002
1003
```

One thing you might want to do is make a single function `composed` from a list of your functions:

```
q)f:{x+1}
q)g:{2*x}
q)h:{x+1+2}
q)(('[;])/)(f;g;h)
{x+1}{2*x}{x+1+2}
q)composed:(('[;])/)(f;g;h)
q)t:([]a:1 2 3)
q)update composed a from t
a
--
9
11
13
```

so that you only have a single function in your update statement, and it should scale.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, I wasn’t sure because I hadn’t seen anything documented. Also, I’m getting used to the syntax but if i understand your composed variable ((‘[;])/): translates to “each argument over the following arguments (f;g;h) and calculates function h first. There is a call order to my functions so I’m just trying to make sure I call them in the correct order.

Comment: Yes, so ' is the compose operator, it takes two single argument functions and composes them to return one single argument function. If you want to compose a list of more than two functions, you have to use the over iterator. Given an argument `x`, the function will calculate `h x` first, then `g (h x)`, then `f (g (h x))`, so the whole thing is equivalent to doing `{f g h x}`.